# No persistence provider for entitymanager named xyz

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I have a JavaFX Maven project in IntelliJ, which uses Hibernate. When the app is starting, I am getting the following error message:

> No persistence provider for entitymanager named xyz

Why? My *META-INF/persistence.xml* is located in *myproject/src/main/resources* (the directory is checked as resource folder in project settings).
I am sure I've downloaded all Hibernate JARs via Maven.

My persistence.xml is correct:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
      <persistence-unit name="xyz">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>entity.User</class>
        <properties>
          <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:java.sqlite"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver"/>
          <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none"/>
          <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

Java code:

```
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("xyz");
```

In my an old non-Maven project the code above worked fine.

Comment: Did you check your built artifact? Does it contain persistence.xml and in the correct location?

Comment: Simply rename WEB-INF in META-INF and it should work

Comment: It's my mistake during writing the question. The folder is named **META-INF** not WEB-INF.

Comment: if you are using Hibernate 5.2 try `<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>`

Comment: Ejb.hibernatepersistence is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

your persistence.xml must be located in the META-INF folder

Comment: It's my mistake during writing the question. The folder is named **META-INF** not WEB-INF.

Answer (score 0):

There was a different context and solution in my case:

## Context:

see the log below:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.h2.Driver] at URL [jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test]
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=sa}
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
...
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named NewPersistenceUnit`
```

## Solution:

As its clear from logs above, persistenceUnit has been found and some data like dialect, username and password is extracted.

There was problem in mapping of entities. By commenting out `@Entity` one by one on entities, I was able to find the problem and solve it, without any change in `persistence.xml` file.

I have no idea why error like `No Persistence provider for EntityManager named X` should be shown when there is a problem in entity mapping!